# Website issue - large, high res images displaying as low quality on iPhone; loading high quality on Android and Desktop

Tags: css, responsive

I have a website with large, high-quality images. The quality level looks as expected on Desktop and mobile devices when using Android.

However, I have issues with iPhones when I zoom into the pictures. I tested with Safari and Chrome and the same issue happens with picture quality being too low.

Example of URL / image: **https://www.honestmaps.com/Beaver-Creek/1728**

My view on iPhone: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBSCo.jpg**

This shows how low quality and blurry it gets when zoomed in on an iPhone device.

**Questions**:

1. Does it show up like this for the rest of you on an iPhone device?
2. Is there any code that can be implemented to force the high-resolution image and prevent iOS from reducing the quality level?

Another large image to review is this one: **https://honestmaps.com/Snowbird/1715**

You can see how sharp it stays zooming in on a desktop, but on my iPhone, it loses sharpness.

A recent finding on iPhones is when I select "Request Desktop Website" via the aA icon, the image quality is very high.

I am trying to figure out what drives the serving of lower-quality images. Is it the network carrier, a phone setting, or something within the code? Is there a way to hardcode something to force the full-quality image to be loaded as with the desktop/android setting?

*Actions taken so far: tested on various devices, browsers, settings.*

Comment: Is honestmaps.com your site and something you can change, or is it just a example? For the later case, you are out of luck.

Comment: This is my website so we can change things to improve it.